# libGDX: Let an object rotate in the direction in which it moves

Tags: java, android, libgdx, rotation, direction

I want to turn my player in the direction he is looking at. The whole is so similar to the behavior of the Bird in FlappyBird. He always looks in the direction in which he moves. I am programming this in Android Studio with libGDX and I have a class in which the game is played and one in which I have information about my player.

I have unfortunately no code example, because everything I have, would explain nothing and would make the situation only more complicated.

Please write a comment if you are confused.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Have you ever tried `batch.draw(region, x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation) could` ? you could rotate the image by your means. I'm still confused what's your question meaning.

Comment: Do you use `Sprite` class or not ?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is a way to flip the sprite. Sadly, I don't think libgdx supports this. But what you could do is draw 2 images of your sprite(one in each direction) or use some drawing program to flip your current image. Then in your sprite class, in your update or render method you would change the sprite image to the corresponding direction using `sprite.set(new Texture())`

Comment: Okay, thanks. Then I wil try to solve the problem in another way!